# Can I get the page number of included PDF page?

Tags: pdfpages

I have to put some academic papers at the end of a document, but only include a subset of their pages (due to the page limitations in our project).  Now, I would like to mark each included page with the original page number of the PDF paper I'm including.

Here is my MWE to illustrate the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1-2,4},picturecommand={\put(30,30){\makebox{Lorem Ipsum p. XX}}}]{lorem.pdf}

\end{document}
```

I created a second PDF called lorem.pdf by just typesetting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-25]
\end{document}
```

which creates a 4-page document lorem.pdf.  Now, when I include only parts of the paper, namely pages 1, 2, and 4, I would like to fill in these numbers in the 'picturecommand' text instead of XX.  Is there a way to reference that number there?

Comment: Just in general: I recommend to use `article` instead of the `minimal` class, even for minimal documents. `minimal` is more a code example than a real class and has no real benefit, but can cause some issues because not all normal things are set.

Comment: Why not do `pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}` and let the included pdf show its own page number? (instead of `picturecommand`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your input document (`lorem.pdf`) has no pages numbers and that the page numbers specified by the key-value `pages={1-2,4}` are the actual page numbers in the source document, the macro `\AM@page` contains the value you're after:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\includepdf[
   pages={1-2,4},
   picturecommand={\put(30,30){\makebox{Lorem Ipsum p.\ \AM@page}}}]
  {lorem.pdf}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

The above MWE prints

```
Lorem Ipsum p. 1
Lorem Ipsum p. 2
Lorem Ipsum p. 4
```

in the lower-left corner.

If the above conditions are not met, then it would be possible to temporarily modify `\AM@page` to be a certain shift from the given values.

Comment: hmph that's simpler than mine, I'll delete

Comment: yes, the conditions were exactly as you stated. Thanks!